# When will Apple stop supporting previous iOS?

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store, ios11

I've got an app that hasn't been updated since a few years ago. It currently supports iOS 8 and later.

With the iOS 11 coming up this September, I heard that Apple will stop to support the iOS 8 at the same time.

What should I do to keep the app in the AppStore?

Thanks in advance

Comment: as far as I know, older apps will not be removed from the App Store even if they don't support newer iOS.But if your app is completely incompatible to work with iOS 11 people may never download it. So no point in keeping it in App Store any way. Download developer preview of iOS 11 test how your app works with it, if its working without crash and fine ignore it will still work if it doesn't consider reshipping it with proper iOS 11 changes :)

Comment: Thank you @SandeepBhandari. It is really relieving to hear that because I can't find anything related to this queries.

Comment: I had an app which I had created for iOS 6 when iOS 7 came there was a huge change I expected my app to be taken down but it still exists won't work on iOS 10 though but still exists :P

Answer (score 1):

Currently, a few iOS 5 apps still seem to be in the App Store (and a few still seem to be functional on current iOS 10 devices).  **However**:

iOS 11 appears to only support running 64-bit apps on 64-bit iOS devices.  The first iOS version to support running arm64 slices was iOS 7.  So any apps that are iOS 6 or earlier will no longer run after an iOS device is updated to iOS 11 (which is expected to start happening sometime circa mid-to-late September 2017).  Any iOS 7 or 8 apps (submitted before 2015) that did not include 64-bit support will also no longer run after iOS 11 is released and older device's are updated.

Apple has also been contacting developers and removing iOS apps from the App store that do not contain 64-bit support.

If your app does not contain 64-bit support (an arm64 slice), and you wish to keep it in the App Store, you will need to update it with 64-bit support and submit that update to Apple.